# Easiest way to join list of ints in Python?

Tags: python

What is the most convenient way to join a list of `int`s to form a `str` without *spaces*?
For example `[1, 2, 3]` will turn `'1,2,3'`. (without spaces).

I know that `','.join([1, 2, 3])` would raise a TypeError.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print ','.join(map(str,[1, 2, 3])) #Prints: 1,2,3
```

Mapping str prevents the `TypeError`

Answer (score 6):

```
','.join(str(x) for x in ints)
```

should be the most Pythonic way.

Answer (score 3):

I like `','.join(str(i) for i in lst)`, but it's really not much different than `map`

Comment: Actually `str.join` will be faster with a list than with a genexp ;-)

Comment: @thefourtheye -- yes, I know.  That's well documented _for CPython_.  But in python3.x, the `map` becomes an iterable (non-list) anyway.  Very rarely does that effect the total runtime of your program in any appreciable way though.  You'd need to demonstrate that it's a bottleneck before I'd change the code I think.

Comment: You don't have to change it, but since lists will be faster, List comprehension is an option.

Comment: Yeah, it is ... But I don't like the look of the extra brackets :-)